# Goolgle Chart vertical labels

Tags: google-visualization, axis-labels, pygooglechart

I can't don't find the property to modify the size of the label font.
My labels are not clearly displayed in front of the bars and some of them is missing.

I tried with the property below but nothing changed.

vAxis:{titleTextStyle:  { color: '#000', fontSize: 8, bold: true,  italic: false }}

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

see the [config options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options) for the Timeline, there is no `vAxis`.

use instead...

```
timeline:{rowLabelStyle: { color: '#000', fontSize: 8, bold: true, italic: false }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but nothing has changed in the display
var options = { bars: 'horizontal', isStacked: 'percent', height: 300, legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3}, timeline: {rowLabelStyle: { color: '#000', fontSize: 3, bold: true, italic: false }}, hAxis: { minValue: 0,  ticks: [0, .3, .6, .9, 1] } };